# Text field validation rule

Tags: validation

In contact object I have a Title field as type text. If anybody enters a number in this field, it should throw an error. How can I achieve this with avalidation rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error Condition Formula For validation rule..

```
NOT(REGEX(Title__c, "^[A-Z a-z ]+$"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [regex](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#REGEX) to validate.

```
REGEX(SSN__c, "^[A-Za-z ]+$")
```

if it return true then your string is correct otherwise it return false and throw error.